# Spring boot static where clause with JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a RESTful Spring Boot project that fetches data from MySQL DB.

I want to print just all categories that have active field equal to 1
and I want to apply that for all method in CategoryRepository Class: `findAll`, `findByParentId` ..etc.

```
package com.userService.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.userService.entities.Category;

public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    @Query("where active =1")
    public List<Category> findByParentId(int id);



}
```

I tried to use the query method but it doesn't work and gave me an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate as your persistence provider, you can take advantage of `@Where` clause on the entity level:

```
@Where(clause = "active =1")
@Entity
public  class Category{
```

This will be applied to all queries that go through the persistence provider.

Comment: is there a way that i can choose some properties in the Entity class to be shown  and the others not.

Comment: What if I want to select active = 0 later ?

Comment: Did someone notice that the `@Where` condition at `@Entity` level it's not applied when we use a composite key?

Answer (score 1):

it could be helpful to you  if you are using the query method you should specify

`select  alias_name  from Category c where condition`

or

`from Category where condition`

or

directly by using method

`findByActive(int id);`

```
public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    @Query("select c from Category c where c.active =1")
    public List<Category> findByParentId(int id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Query` annotation allows to execute native queries. So, I think, you should specify the complete sql as follows

```
@Query("select c from Category c where c.active =1")
```

Comment: This query is not going even to compile.
@Query("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.active = 1")

Comment: I've tried this but it gave me an exception =>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

Comment: hey, you are passing `int id` in `findByParentId`. So, `@Query("select c from Category c where c.active =?1")` should work. `?1` is a placeholder which will be replaced with the actual `id` value